# Flutter Design Popup Menu

Tags: flutter, flutter-design

I want to build a similar popup menu like on google.com.
[image: Popup Menu]

I have wrapped a CircleAvatar widget inside a GestureRecognizer to have the onTap-callback.
Right now im simply calling showMenu() but I feel like I'm very limited with the PopupMenuItem restriction on the items property.

Is there another possibility to achieve the desired result?